# How do we know which type of GC(young/full) is currently being executed in my Java Program using VisualVM or any other tool?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, visualvm

I am doing a performance analysis of a Program using VisualVM tool. I was able to check CPU usage and heap usage of the program but couldn't figure out which type of GC (young GC/full GC) is executing currently. Is there anyway to find it using VisualVM or is there any other tool for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am no VisualVM expert, so I do not know how to do this using. But I can provide you a couple of alternatives

### JSTAT

You can see what kind of gc is being performed by using [jstat](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jstat.html#GUID-5F72A7F9-5D5A-4486-8201-E1D1BA8ACCB5)

First we need to discover the PID of your Java running process. For this, we can use [jps](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jps.html#GUID-6EB65B96-F9DD-4356-B825-6146E9EEC81E). In this example, a running Eclipse IDE.

```sh
jps
10156 org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.5.700.v20200207-2156.jar
```

Now use the following command `jstat -gc 10156 1s`

`1s` refers to the sampling interval. You can use whatever one that fits your needs.

This command outputs a table with a lot of columns, and I am finding it very hard to format (sorry), so please focus on these two ones

- YGC: Number of young generation garbage collection (GC) events.
- FGC: Number of full GC events.

Watching these two counters will give you a general idea of what type of collections are being performed.

### JVM Flags

Besides, you can use a JVM flag

- `-Xlog:gc*` for java 11
- `-XX:+PrintGCDetails` for java 8

Which will print all GC details along the console: memory footprint before/after each collection, time spent, ergonomics ...

Output of this flag is somehow tricky to understand as it depends on your JVM implementation, selected GC, JVM flags ...

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information. That's what I exactly needed - no. of young gcs and no.of full gcs. Also came to know that there is a plugin in VisualVM called Visual GC.